# MULE 4 IntelliJ resolving xsd schemas

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, xsd, mule

I am trying to use IntelliJ as IDE instead of Anypoint Studio because it runs very bad on windows. I've downloaded the plugin, but I'm having troubles setting up the xsd references of the connectors, it keeps complaining that it cannot find the xsd.

The mule xsd are pointing to a location over the internet which doesn't exist, I think that it must be resolved against the pom dependencies, but I don't know how to tell this to the IDE.

Here's an example of my mule app (which runs fine on Anypoint Studio):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:email="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email"
  xmlns:ftps="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftps"
  xmlns:mongo="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo"
  xmlns:java="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/java"
  xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking"
  xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
  xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
  xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
  xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
  xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit"
  xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/java http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/java/current/mule-java.xsd
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo/current/mule-mongo.xsd
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftps http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftps/current/mule-ftps.xsd
  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email/current/mule-email.xsd">
<flow name="post:ProcessPayment" doc:id="ccaba1bf-94b0-412c-895d-6bc118b0b878"> ...
```

And this is the error shown from IntelliJ:
[image]

Comment: What Imtellij plugin are you using?

Comment: this one: https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/data-weave-intellij-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You are using a plugin for DataWeave 2.0, it is not meant to support Mule 4 XML configuration files